# swift: photos from firebase not showing in table view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I already looked at similar questions and problems and tried what they suggested but none seemed to work and i cant seem to find why nothing is showing in the view. The following is my code.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var postsTableView: UITableView!
    
    var posts = NSMutableArray()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        postsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 521
        postsTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        postsTableView.delegate = self
        postsTableView.dataSource = self as UITableViewDataSource
        loadData()

    }
    func loadData() {
        Database.database().reference().child("posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let postsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                for post in postsDictionary {
                    self.posts.add(post.value)
                }
                self.postsTableView.reloadData()
            }
            
        })
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return self.posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

        let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
      
        if let imageName = post["posts"] as? String {
            let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("posts/\(String(describing: imageName))")
            imageRef.getData(maxSize: 15 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    //successful
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!) //create an image with data sent from database
                    cell.postImageView.image = image
                 
                    cell.postImageView.alpha = 0
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                       
                        cell.postImageView.alpha = 1
                    })
                } else {
                    //error
                    print("Error downloading the image: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                }
                tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
        return cell
    }


}
```

The screen just shows empty cells of the table view.

This is the console when the app loads.
[image]

Also excuse me if I didnt format my question correctly.

Comment: I think imageRef is deallocating with its callback, so there is no callback called. Did You check if callback is called at all?

Comment: Tableviews are designed to be lightweight and responsive - loading data from within a cell is going to affect performance and drive up costs. Cells get dequeued and reused all the time so every time that happens that code has to re-download the image. You should load your data in to a dataSource and the tableView pulls it's data from that datasource which keeps it fast. Look into that as well as prefetching and [caching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/asynchronously_loading_images_into_table_and_collection_views).

Comment: Oh, don't do this `tableView.reloadData()` within a function that already calls it. e.g. .reloadData calls `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt` so don't call it again from within that function as that will call an endless cycle of reloading data.

Comment: A couple of other things. You should not be doing this `var posts = NSMutableArray()` at this point. Let's be Swifty and create a Post Class to store each posts data and store that in an array `let postsArray = [PostClass]()`.  Second this `if let postsDictionary = snapshot.value` will make your posts be in random order - dictionaries have no order. Last is your array contains [String, AnyObject]. What is AnyObject? It's just a name so leave it as a string which avoids `String(describing: imageName)`. Also are all of the keys called 'post'? What's your Firebase structure?

Comment: @Jay by keys do you mean collections in firebase? So far i only have users and posts as collections. I will try and implement a class for posts but can you give me a pointer or tell me where to look on how to load the data to a dataSource. Can i just implement caching or do i need to do something else? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at [Dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_dictionaries.htm). Dictionaries are composed of key: value pairs [key: value] and in your case [String; Any]. This `imageName = post["posts"]` goes into the post dictionary and looks up the value for key "posts". See [TableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) for details and  [Apple Tutorial: Create a tableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html)

Comment: You may or may not need caching - it depends of the quantity of data and or if your paginating your data or using other techniques to only load a small 'chunk' of data at a time. We would need know that and also how your Firebase is structured. As far as loading data to a dataSource, see about but you're aleady doing that with `var posts = NSMutableArray()` but it probably be better to be an array of posts with the images.

Answer (score 0):

1. As Prettygeek mentioned, first of all, check if the `completion` of `getData` is being called. If not, try to retain `imageRef` outside of `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` scope (just for debugging).
2. Check on which thread `getData` calls its `completion`, most likely it's different from the `main` thread, and you shouldn't make calls to UIKit from the thread other than `main`. `DispatchQueue.main.async` will get handy there.

Comment: You guys were right it wasn't getting called but even after the `if let imageName..` i tried printing and it didn't run, what do you suggest? Also i wasn't sure how to check which thread `getData` gets called on tbh.

Comment: Just a FYI. DispatchQueue.main.async is unneeded within Firebase closures. All networking calls are done on a background thread and all UI calls are done on the main thread.